# remove consequtive repeating values python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list for which I need to remove continuously repeating values.

For example:
input:

```
Xin = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,1]
```

output:

```
Yout = [1,2,3,2,3,1]
```

(Zero is not a legal value in this case).

My current code is this:

```
Yout = np.zeros(len(Xin))          #initialize a list

for i in range(len(Xin)):          
    if Xin[i] != Xin[i-1]:     
        You[j] = Xin[i]
        j = j + 1

Yout = np.ma.masked_equal(Yout,0) #mask all the zeros
Yout = Yout.compressed()          #Remove all the masks
```

Someone had answered this for 'R', but I need this for Python.

Comment: your current code seems to miss the initialization of `j` and some imports - hence it produces errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,1])
print(a)
# [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 1]

b = a[a != np.r_[a[1:], None]]
print(b)
# [1 2 3 2 3 1]
```

Comment: This works great.

Comment: Can you please explain the syntax ?

Comment: it uses `advanced indexing in numpy`. if you compare two numpy arrays, they're element-wise compared. `np.r_[a[1:], None]` precedes one element over just `a`. so `a != np.r_[a[1:], None]` will have True at which consecutive elements are different.

Comment: Thanks. and how do I mark the index in which the element has changed ?

Comment: @MalcolmRest you can use `np.where(a != np.r_[a[1:], None])[0]`